# Duplicate values in List after retrieving data through BufferedReader

Tags: java, list, bufferedreader

Trying a simple example where I am entering the data through the console and adding them to a List. But the values of the last name,age entered repeats itself in the List.

```
private List<User> getData() throws IOException{
    User user=new User();
    List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter name,age:");
        String values=reader.readLine();
        String[] value=values.split(",");
        user.setName(value[0]);
        user.setAge(value[1]);
        userList.add(user);
    }
    return userList;

}
```

On printing the userList, its seems that the list is populated with final values I entered through the console.
Example,

Enter name,age: `rickesh,22`
Enter name,age: `john,21`

Contents of List: [john 22,john 22]

```
public class User { 
    private String age;
    private String name;

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that I s**k at my basic java skills. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new User in a for loop.

```
private List<User> getData() throws IOException{    
List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter name,age:");
    String values=reader.readLine();
    String[] value=values.split(",");
    User user=new User();
    user.setName(value[0]);
    user.setAge(value[1]);
    userList.add(user);
}
return userList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have created only one instance of `User`, which you keep updating on every iteration. effectively you'll end up adding that same instance with the data pertaining to the last iteration. Try creating a new `User` instance inside that `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move this instruction:

```
User user=new User();
```

to the `for` loop as shown here:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    User user=new User();
    System.out.println("Enter name,age:");
    String values=reader.readLine();
    String[] value=values.split(",");
    user.setName(value[0]);
    user.setAge(value[1]);
    userList.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the new User Object inside for loop your problem will get solved:

```
private List<User> getData() throws IOException{
      User user=null;
    List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        user =new User();//create new user here
        System.out.println("Enter name,age:");
        String values=reader.readLine();
        String[] value=values.split(",");
        user.setName(value[0]);
        user.setAge(value[1]);
        userList.add(user);
    }
    return userList;

}
```